# Write html code to JSP through JSP write

Tags: jsp

Hi i am generating dynamically html code and trying to write that code to jsp code. but i m not able to write it.
Although it write same code if i put in into double quotes passed it as argument to jspwriter.
  example :

```
pageContext.getOut().print(sbCutDetails.toString());
```

this is not working

```
pageContext.getOut().print("<td  width ="368.24646" id='0'  title="INSERT MACRO SLICE_0" bgcolor="WHITE" onclick="javascript:showMacro('null','111.0','22','0','111.0','0.0','0')">&nbsp;</td><td  width ="331.75354" id='1'  title="ADD MACRO TO BOTTOM_0" bgcolor="WHITE" onclick="javascript:showMacro('Edit Cut','100.0','12','1','100.0','111.0','0')">&nbsp;</td>");
```

it is working.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? and note the pattern `" "" "`

Comment: Hi i my application at some places we need dynamic html code,tht i m generating throguh tld ; but generated tld is tht i passed into second argument of jspwriter. when i m passing dynamic value as argument jspwriter is not able to write html code on jsp page bt when i m passing as fixed value as argument same code. it s working.

Comment: where is the code to generate `sbCutDetails` ?

Comment: i have not written code to generate sbCutDetails.but it is finally generates as :<td  width ="368.24646" id='0'  title="INSERT MACRO SLICE_0" bgcolor="WHITE" onclick="javascript:showMacro('null','111.0','22','0','111.0','0.0','0')">&nbsp;</td><td  width ="331.75354" id='1'  title="ADD MACRO TO BOTTOM_0" bgcolor="WHITE" onclick="javascript:showMacro('Edit Cut','100.0','12','1','100.0','111.0','0')">&nbsp;</td>

Answer (score 1):

If sbCutDetails is a StringBuilder and you did append the same text to it, it should produce the same output.

Comment: Ya sbCutDetails is a string buffet and i am appending same code tht i passed into second argument of jspwriter. but i m not able to guess the problem why it not writing html on jsp page....

Comment: do you use the code inside the JSP? in this case, simply put <%= sbCutDetails.toString() %>

Comment: no code i m generating in TLD(java file ) and writing it to jsp through jsp writer.

Comment: do you use ...getOut.append(..) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think jsp scrip-let you need to use this time for dynamic binding "<% ... %>" with simple HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can check by using `<%jsp:usebean ... %>`